# Help me automate a procedure in excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have an excel sheet with values in columns A, B and C like this:

```
      A      B      C
1    8.22   1.99902 32.48974
2    8.22   3.04698 33.92426
3    8.22   2.26374 33.1547
4    8.22   2.78227 33.2593
6    8.22   2.46798 33.34269
6    8.22   2.57802 33.67131
7    8.22   2.46798 32.7427
8    8.22   2.57802 33.07131
```

There is also a cell (say for example F1) containing a value that can only be 1,2 or 3.

I would like to create a `commandbutton` to perform the following job:
For each pair of lines (which cosnist a group) insert 2 new lines below them, and populate them with values like this (suppose we are dealing with the group residing in lines 9 and 10)

```
If F1 = 1 THEN
A11 = A10   B11 = B10   C11 = C9
A12 = A10   B12 = B9    C12 = C10

If F1 = 2 THEN
A11 = A10   B11 = B10   C11 = C9
A12 = A9   B12 = B10    C12 = C10

If F1 = 3 THEN
A11 = A10   B11 = B9   C11 = C10
A12 = A9   B12 = B10    C12 = C10
```

Finaly set the background color for the newely inserted lines to yellow.

Could you please help me accomplish this task?

P.S. Once a button like this was pressed, what would you recommend for an `Undo` capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your data start at Row 1 and the commandbutton's name is CommandButton1, try adding the following code in CommandButton1 click event. I used a bottom-up approach because it was easier for me to handle row numbers while looping.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lines_count As Integer
    Dim fixed_column As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    lines_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A"))
    fixed_column = Range("F1").Value

    For i = lines_count + 2 To 4 Step -2 
        Rows(i - 1 & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        Select Case fixed_column
        Case 1
            Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = Cells(i - 2, 1).Value
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 2, 1).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = Cells(i - 2, 2).Value
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 3, 2).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = Cells(i - 3, 3).Value
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 2, 3).Value
        Case 2
            Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = Cells(i - 2, 1).Value
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 3, 1).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = Cells(i - 2, 2).Value
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 2, 2).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = Cells(i - 3, 3).Value
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 2, 3).Value
        Case 3
            Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = Cells(i - 2, 1).Value
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 3, 1).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = Cells(i - 3, 2).Value
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 2, 2).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = Cells(i - 2, 3).Value
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 2, 3).Value
        End Select
        Range("A" & CStr(i - 1) & ":C" & CStr(i)).Select
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

- You should try to create Macros and then see what kind of code they produce.  This will help you see what VBA code is needed to manipulate the Excel sheet.
- After you create a few macros, learn how to do loops so that you can run the process multiple times for all of the cells that you need.
- You can't undo the results of a macro.  You might *try* to write a separate function to undo the results of a previous function, but sounds like a ton of work.  I would recommend creating a copy of the worksheet you have and working with a new sheet for your development phase.

This should get you started.  There are plenty of people on SO that could figure this out for you, but perhaps this would be a good problem to step into a little bit at a time; then ask questions when you stock on a specific detail.

For example, if you see code generated by the macro that looks like `ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Select`, you might ask, "I see how to select a single cell. How do I select an entire Row?"  That will get you more targeted answers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Exactly what I usually do. I think recording macros and analysing the code is the best way to do what you want in Excel without having to learn all the specifics, which are quite bad for some functions.